# How to block all connections on all ports using iptables?

Tags: 18.04, iptables

I am trying to protect myself from ddos and limiting all users with more then 5 connection request to connect to my server.
I am trying to use this one, but it is not working, it actually blocks even 1 connection to most of the users:

iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 0:65535 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 5 -j REJECT

If I do same command but just on 1 port, it works on that port and connections are limited

iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 5 -j REJECT

where do I make a mistake when i select all ports?

Comment: does this anwer your question [UDP conn limits](https://serverfault.com/questions/375616/limit-udp-connections-per-ip-iptables) ?

Comment: Hello, mitigating DDoS is not so easy... You know, the first *D* means distributed, which on other hand means multiple IPs... So I would suggest you to spend few hours with this great article: [DDoS Protection With IPtables: The Ultimate Guide](https://javapipe.com/blog/iptables-ddos-protection/). Here is a quotation from the guide: *You’ll find that most if not all guides on how to block DDoS attacks using iptables use the filter table and the INPUT chain for anti-DDoS rules.
The issue with this approach is that the INPUT chain is only processed after the PREROUTING and FORWARD chains....*

Comment: thanks, but still did not figure it out, as i said when i add only 1 port in dport, then it works blocking on that port, but when i add port range then to some client it does not allow even 1 connection to connect

Comment: I doubt if it'll make any difference, but try deleting the port stuff entirely, which then implies all ports. So: `iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 5 -j REJECT`. With all your questions, you need to follow up on them and indicate if answers or comments helped or not, and if not why not. For this question I suggest you add some example information, as I am not convinced your issues are what you say they are.